# Find and FindNext in VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am working on Excel macro. What i need when getting data from another excel sheet, code should first check if there is any other row with the same FundName and if found then conditions apply.

I am just giving the sample of Excel Sheet from which the FundId is to be checked :

```
S.No    Funds
1        A
2        B
3        C
4        D
5        A
```

Code is given below:

```
Set shtData = wbraw.Sheets(1) ' this line is correct

Set CCell = shtData.Cells.Find("Funds", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0)

Set DCell = CCell.End(xlDown)

Dim SearchString as String
SearchString  = "A"  

Set FindRow = shtData.Range(CCell, DCell).Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Set NextRow = shtData.Range(CCell, DCell).FindNext(After:=FindRow)
```

Above two lines in code not working as i want it should be. Let say if SearchString is set to "A" then FindRow and NextRow both should have the value. And if SearchString is set to "B" then as per given excel sheet FindRow should have the value but NextRow returns Nothing so that I can apply my conditions.

Please if anyone can help me.

Comment: Why don't you just use `COUNTIF()` instead to see if there's more than one?

Comment: thanks... can you please give me the code for the same as above conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Find` will use the first cell of `Range` for the `After` parameter, if it is not specified, therefore the search is started after B2, and thus the first cell it finds is B6.
If the order is important for you then call `Find` with the last cell provided as `After`:

```
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0

    With shtData.Range(CCell, DCell)
        Set c = .Find(SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=DCell)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                counter = counter + 1
                Debug.Print "The next match #" & counter & " is " & c.Address

                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: what if i also want to find the next occurrence of the same SearchString. ??

Comment: It is ok to call `FindNext` the way you did, but you should place it into a Do While loop in case there are more than two values.

Comment: let say i have only one value in FindNext , i have tried it not working . Can you please give me a woeking code for FindNext.?

Comment: I edited my answer and added code for the FindNext part

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
Set FindRow = shtData.Range(CCell, DCell).Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Set NextRow = shtData.Range(CCell, DCell).FindNext(After:=FindRow)
```

With:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CCell.EntireColumn, SearchString) > 1 Then
   'Duplicate found, do something here
Else
   'Unique string, do something here
End If
```

Or

```
If Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & CCell.EntireColumn.Address & "," & SearchString & ")") > 1 Then
   'Duplicate found, do something here
Else
   'Unique string, do something here
End If
```

Comment: thanks ... but if i need to get the value from the second occurrence(Duplicate found) of fund then how could i get it?