# Anyway to have Find method start at the very firs cell ie A1

Tags: excel, vba

I have some really simple code that is looking for the first cell (`Rng`) to contain a certain string (`FindString`) cells in a range (`A:A`). Based on the data (which varies) sometimes this string is in the very first cell. The find function seems to search after the very first cell (`A1`). I can get around this by inserting a blank row at the top of my data but that seems like an ugly way to do it.

My code is simply:

```
Set Rng = Range("A:A").Find(FindString)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the After parameter to the last cell of your range, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959717/find-and-findnext-in-vba/27961491#27961491)

Comment: Thanks. It works! Didn't understand how the Method wraps round.